# Daemonizing tool for Gunicorn Centos Nginx and Django

Tags: centos, nginx, centos5, django

I have set up a basic centos server and through that tested certain technologies.

Currently I am running django-1.3, Nginx with FastCGI - works like a charm

I have noticed that as soon as my latest commits are pulled and Nginx restarted, they don't take effect immediately, which lead me to another thread saying that most items are loaded into memoery and will eventually expire.

So everytime I want pull up to date code, I have to SSH into my server, change the `nginx.conf` file, start a new FCGI process with the new port specified in the nginx.conf file and then restart / upgrade nginx in order for it to take effect --- FRUSTRATION

I have been testing Gunicorn with Nginx and Django on Heroku, all works fine and really quick.

My question, what is the best way to keep track of all this, are their tools to help with daemonizing? What are they and could you point out some tips?

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

I hear a lot about [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) for django+gunicorn, though I'm using upstart myself.